# Best method for comparing multiple ranging measures

Tags: multiple-comparisons, equivalence

I've been asked to give some advice for some clinicians who are comparing two different methods of blood pressure measurement.  I suggested to them that we should proceed with a two-one-sided-test technique to determine equivalence of the two techniques.

Unfortunately I have now learned that the clinicians have multiple measurements of blood pressure by each of the two methods and that the blood pressure can be quite variable within each patient during the period of observation (they are theatre cases).

Is it possible to use some multiple regression technique to perform an equivalence test?  Can I simply use confidence intervals to determine variability between the two techniques whilst accounting for inter-patient variability if I use the patients as factors in the regression model?

Sorry it's an amateur question, but despite the Masters degree, I still feel like quite the amateur!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like [mixed effects or multi-level modelling](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-mixed-models.pdf) is what you want here.

Comment: Thanks for your response John.  I'm not sure how I would go about using mixed-effects modelling to test from equivalence - do you have any examples?  Thanks!  Sam.

Comment: equivalence of what?  Your question doesn't mention this.  Perhaps edit the question to be more precise.